# yahoo changed its API or partially down?

Tags: yahoo-api, yfinance

does anyone know whats happening with the `yfinance` module?
I'm writing a huge web app on stock portfolio optimisation and I was relying on that module. Now I have to modify the whole thing...

any assistance appreciated!

Y

```
import yfinance as yf

msft = yf.Ticker("AAPL")

# get stock info
msft.info
```

prints

{'regularMarketPrice': None,
'preMarketPrice': None,
'logo_url': '',
'trailingPegRatio': 2.6609}

I used to get a huge dictionary but now I get back only this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like I was running an older version of yfinance in my venv.. after the update I got the full dict

```
ticker = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
info = ticker.info
info.keys()


dict_keys(['zip', 'sector', 'fullTimeEmployees', 'longBusinessSummary', 'city', 'phone', 'state', 'country', 'companyOfficers', 'website', 'maxAge', 'address1', 'industry', 'ebitdaMargins', 'profitMargins', 'grossMargins', 'operatingCashflow', 'revenueGrowth', 'operatingMargins', 'ebitda', 'targetLowPrice', 'recommendationKey', 'grossProfits', 'freeCashflow', 'targetMedianPrice', 'currentPrice', 'earningsGrowth', 'currentRatio', 'returnOnAssets', 'numberOfAnalystOpinions', 'targetMeanPrice', 'debtToEquity', 'returnOnEquity', 'targetHighPrice', 'totalCash', 'totalDebt', 'totalRevenue', 'totalCashPerShare', 'financialCurrency', 'revenuePerShare', 'quickRatio', 'recommendationMean', 'exchange', 'shortName', 'longName', 'exchangeTimezoneName', 'exchangeTimezoneShortName', 'isEsgPopulated', 'gmtOffSetMilliseconds', 'quoteType', 'symbol', 'messageBoardId', 'market', 'annualHoldingsTurnover', 'enterpriseToRevenue', 'beta3Year', 'enterpriseToEbitda', '52WeekChange', 'morningStarRiskRating', 'forwardEps', 'revenueQuarterlyGrowth', 'sharesOutstanding', 'fundInceptionDate', 'annualReportExpenseRatio', 'totalAssets', 'bookValue', 'sharesShort', 'sharesPercentSharesOut', 'fundFamily', 'lastFiscalYearEnd', 'heldPercentInstitutions', 'netIncomeToCommon', 'trailingEps', 'lastDividendValue', 'SandP52WeekChange', 'priceToBook', 'heldPercentInsiders', 'nextFiscalYearEnd', 'yield', 'mostRecentQuarter', 'shortRatio', 'sharesShortPreviousMonthDate', 'floatShares', 'beta', 'enterpriseValue', 'priceHint', 'threeYearAverageReturn', 'lastSplitDate', 'lastSplitFactor', 'legalType', 'lastDividendDate', 'morningStarOverallRating', 'earningsQuarterlyGrowth', 'priceToSalesTrailing12Months', 'dateShortInterest', 'pegRatio', 'ytdReturn', 'forwardPE', 'lastCapGain', 'shortPercentOfFloat', 'sharesShortPriorMonth', 'impliedSharesOutstanding', 'category', 'fiveYearAverageReturn', 'previousClose', 'regularMarketOpen', 'twoHundredDayAverage', 'trailingAnnualDividendYield', 'payoutRatio', 'volume24Hr', 'regularMarketDayHigh', 'navPrice', 'averageDailyVolume10Day', 'regularMarketPreviousClose', 'fiftyDayAverage', 'trailingAnnualDividendRate', 'open', 'toCurrency', 'averageVolume10days', 'expireDate', 'algorithm', 'dividendRate', 'exDividendDate', 'circulatingSupply', 'startDate', 'regularMarketDayLow', 'currency', 'trailingPE', 'regularMarketVolume', 'lastMarket', 'maxSupply', 'openInterest', 'marketCap', 'volumeAllCurrencies', 'strikePrice', 'averageVolume', 'dayLow', 'ask', 'askSize', 'volume', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh', 'fromCurrency', 'fiveYearAvgDividendYield', 'fiftyTwoWeekLow', 'bid', 'tradeable', 'dividendYield', 'bidSize', 'dayHigh', 'coinMarketCapLink', 'regularMarketPrice', 'preMarketPrice', 'logo_url', 'trailingPegRatio'])
```